# How to deploy 3-tier web app on cloud with CI/CD setup

Tags: web-applications, web-hosting

I am planning to host my own web App,and I want to do it in the most automated way with proper CI/CD setup
My plan is as below

1) I will have 3 tier architecture, a db server to store my data, I want to use mongo db or PostgreSQL
2) A back end server that will interact with the DB
3) A node express webserver which will serve my Single page web app, and it will make call to my back end server apis for data, I am planning to use react and node express

I am now confused on how to deploy and host my webapp

I am clear that I will have have a 2 git repos
one for my backend api service 
another for my web server and react app

I will setup an automatic CI/CD pipleline for both of them, so that it gets deployed on every commit to master

I also know, I need to buy domain name, the endpoint for accessing my app on the web

But the part I am not sure is, where to host all the servers, db server, api server, webserver

I watched some tutorial, where I saw people are using godaddy web hosting, and they are using C-pannel to upload the static site files to run the website

but I want to setup proper CI/CD piplelin using jenkins or trevis

I believe I need to buy a vm from digital ocean or aws, and then I need to map my bought dns name to the ip address of the vm, and in the vm I need to run all the servers

I am not very sure if this is the correct path to take, or my understanding have some gap here,
I want to know what is the best practice here

Comment: There's way too much to address in this question in a single answer.. however you don't need a webserver for your front end. Just use netlify or some other cdn service https://www.netlify.com/

Comment: I am confused here, when you say I dont need a webserver, then who runs the webserver ? netlify ?

Comment: Correct, netlify is a cdn service (among many other things). It links to your github and automatically builds and deploys your branches.

Comment: since your frontend is just static assets, your own webserver is overhead you don't need to bother with. of course with your backend it's a different story, which there are many ways of doing what you want

Comment: Is it possible to do CI/CD of a react app with netlify? and whats the difference between netlify and the type of hosting godaddy or horeku provides ?

Comment: netlify is designed from the groundup with CI/CD. it's probably the best CI service that exists right now. heroku is good, but it's for full stack stuff. godaddy is shit don't use it

Comment: oh and netlify is free, so that's obviously a big reason to use it